# how to download pdf with name that i set in my code by Restlet Client

Tags: c#

How to download pdf with name that i set in my code by Restlet Client?

1. RS is one Google plug-in for [API Test Tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/restlet-client-rest-api-t/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm)
2. The question is that I want to download PDF with the name that I set in my code ,but when I click download link in response body ,the PDF's name become to controller's name.
3. If RS can't do that, any other test API tool can do it ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please confirm file name has been set up correctly.just like this

```
string fileName = \\' + 'filename' + \\';
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
```

Comment: i got it ,it's my code error.thanks very much.  i wil mark it as answer.